# Public method returns a "not a function" error when called

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to call a `this` method in my class. When I do that, I get an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.logMe is not a function

I tried removing `this` but it still had an error. Here's my code:

```
function Logger() {
    this.logMe = function() {
    console.log('Log a Message');
  };

  window.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.logMe();
  });
}

var hello = new Logger();
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Quite surprised that not one answer suggested the use of the arrow syntax here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this` is for an anonymous method instead of `Logger`

```
function() {
    // this is about this anonymous method instead of Logger
    this.logMe();
}
```

You can try to use `window.addEventListener('click', this.logMe);` to make you expect.

```js
function Logger() {
    this.logMe = function() {
    console.log('Log a Message');
  };

  window.addEventListener('click', this.logMe);
}

var hello = new Logger();
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternate pattern (passing some message would probably make sense):

```js
var Logger = {
  log: function(msg) {
      if(typeof(msg) != 'undefined') {
          console.log(msg);
      }
  }
};

window.addEventListener('click', function() {
   Logger.log('Log a Message');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function Logger() {
    this.logMe = function() {
    console.log('Log a Message');
  };

  window.addEventListener('click', () => this.logMe(), false);
}

var hello = new Logger();
```

Look at this : https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4

Answer (score -2):

You need to remove *this* and it will work as expected.

```
function Logger() {
  logMe = function() {
    console.log('Log a Message');
  };

  window.addEventListener('click', function() {
        logMe();
  });
}

var hello = new Logger();
```